# Outlook Macro to delete old messages when a new message with same subject arrives

Tags: vba, outlook

Am trying to write a outlook VB macro, to achieve following:

1. Triggers when a new email arrives.
2. Go to a folder inside Inbox - temp1.
3. Check if there is an existing email which matches the subject of
   this new email.
4. Delete the old email.

Code:

```
Option Explicit
Private objNS As Outlook.NameSpace
Private WithEvents objItems As Outlook.Items
Private Sub Application_Start()
    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim objWatchFolder As Outlook.Folder
    Set olApp = Outlook.Application
    Set objNS = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")

    'Set the folder and items to watch:
    Set objWatchFolder = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("temp1")
    Set objItems = objWatchFolder.Items
    Set objWatchFolder = Nothing
End Sub


Private Sub objItems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
    Dim intCount As Integer
    Dim objVariant As Variant

    For intCount = objItems.Count To 1 Step -1
    Set objVariant = objItems.Item(intCount)
        If objVariant.Subject = Item.Subject And objVariant.SentOn < Item.SentOn 
        Then
          objVariant.Delete
        Else
           End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Issue:

Macro not getting triggered.

Notes:

- Have Trust center settings updated to enable macros.
- Have added this code in Class Module
- When I do F5, it doesn't show any MACRO that it can run.

Seeking some expert help pls!

Comment: There may be a second problem in addition to the code being in the wrong module. Are you moving the new item into "temp1"? If as Dmitry Streblechenko suggests, you are not, you have to watch the inbox for new items not "temp1".

Answer (score 0):

(1) You need to handle the `NewMailEx` event of the Application class which is fired when a new item is received in the Inbox. The `NewMailEx` event fires when a new message arrives in the Inbox and before client rule processing occurs. You can use the Entry ID returned in the `EntryIDCollection` array to call the [NameSpace.GetItemFromID](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/namespace-getitemfromid-method-outlook) method and process the item. Use this method with caution to minimize the impact on Outlook performance. However, depending on the setup on the client computer, after a new message arrives in the Inbox, processes like spam filtering and client rules that move the new message from the Inbox to another folder can occur asynchronously. You should not assume that after these events fire, you will always get a one-item increase in the number of items in the Inbox.

(2) It looks like you already know how to get the a subfolder of Inbox:

```
 Set objWatchFolder = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("temp1")
```

(3) To find items with the same subject you need to use the [Find](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff869662.aspx)/[FindNext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff862482.aspx) or [Restrict](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff869597.aspx) methods of the `Items` class instead of iterating over all items in the folder. Read more about these methods in the following articles:

- [How To: Use Find and FindNext methods to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder (C#, VB.NET)](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/20/outlook-find-findnext-retrieve-mail/)
- [How To: Use Restrict method to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/23/outlook-restrict-method-retrieve-mail/)

Also if you need to find items in multiple folders you may find the [AdvancedSearch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb219884.aspx) method of the Application class helpful. The key benefits of using the `AdvancedSearch` method in Outlook are:

- The search is performed in another thread. You don’t need to run another thread manually since the `AdvancedSearch` method runs it automatically in the background.
- Possibility to search for any item types: mail, appointment, calendar, notes etc. in any location, i.e. beyond the scope of a certain folder. The `Restrict` and `Find`/`FindNext` methods can be applied to a particular `Items` collection (see the `Items` property of the Folder class in Outlook).
- Full support for DASL queries (custom properties can be used for searching too). You can read more about this in the [Filtering](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208216%28v=office.12%29) article in MSDN. To improve the search performance, Instant Search keywords can be used if Instant Search is enabled for the store (see the `IsInstantSearchEnabled` property of the Store class).
- You can stop the search process at any moment using the Stop method of the Search class.

See [Advanced search in Outlook programmatically: C#, VB.NET](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2012/05/31/outlook-search-csharp-vbnet/) for more information.

(4) Use the `Delete` method for removing items.

Answer (score 0):

[Items.ItemAdd Event (Outlook)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/items-itemadd-event-outlook) describes how to apply the ItemAdd event in a Class module. You would then use Application_Startup in ThisOutlookSession to initialize objItems.

What you have is code for the ThisOutlookSession module.

Answer (score -1):

You are watching the ItemAdd event on the temp1 folder, not the Inbox.